# Generic country URL link to app in app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I'm just finishing a game for the iOS app store, and I've got Twitter/FB sharing set up. I would like to put the actual App store link into the Twitter/FB msg, but I'm not sure what to put. I've read this info https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html but I'm still not sure what link to put so the game will open up in whatever country the user is in, rather than a specific countries app store.

Right now I've just got it saying

> Hey can you beat my score? play my game in the iOS App store!

Ideally "my game" part would be the actual link to the game in the app store.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://appstore.com/<appname> ?

Comment: Does that work though? I just tried appstore.com/flappy-bird and it couldn't find it, also I can get the link to my game through iTunes, but it's got the country code in it as "us" what if someone opened it up in the UK or some other country?

Comment: I guess an app called flappy-bird doesn't exist? App Store.com/angrybirds for example works.

Comment: I put a - between my 2 games words, so would my link be my-game or mygame ?

Comment: I suggest you read that apple documentation again

Comment: Cool, thanks if you put that in as an answer, i'll accept it.